# Can no longer connect to Visual Studio Team Services using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, azure-devops

Today I tried connecting to Visual Studio Team Services using Visual Studio 2008 and got error tf31002.

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server X. Team Foundation Server URL: Y.

I used to be able to connect successfully using this installation of Visual Studio but this seems to no longer be the case.

This is the url I am using: https://myusername.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
This same url works fine in the browser.

Here are the steps I tried in the specified order:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2008 completely using this tool provided by  Microsoft: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=105801
2. Install Visual Studio 2008 again.
3. Install Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer
4. Install Visual Studio 2008 SP1
5. Install Visual Studio 2008 GDR Update for TFS

After performing the above steps, I am still getting the exact same error.
Also I am able to connect to VS Team Services fine from a Visual Studio 2015 installation on the same computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 is no longer supported when connecting to TFS 2015 and Visual Studio Team Services through the old Team Explorer Client 2008. While it still works (sort of), you'll encounter a number of places where Team Explorer may pop-up an error. I believe this happens at least when you open the Builds.

The officially supported scenario requires you to instead, install a more recent version of Visual Studio side-by-side and install the MSSCCI provider for that more recent version of Visual Studio. As the 2015 version of the MSSCCI has not been released (yet), you'll need to install one of the following combinations:

- Team Explorer 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 update 5 and MSSCCI provider 32-bit
- Team Explorer 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 update 5 and MSSCCI provider 32-bit
- Team Explorer 2010 and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Forward compatibility GDR and the MSSCCI provider 32-bit

Once the MSSCCI provider for Visual Studio 2015 is released, you can use that together with any version of Visual Studio 2015 to connect your Visual Studio 2008.

After installing the MSSCCI provider and matching Team Explorer vesion, you can go into Tools->Options in your VS2008 installation and select the provider under the options for Source Control.

[All download links can be found on my blog where I keep the links current](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html).

Comment: Yea, I thought it was something like that. I will give what you said a try with VS 2013 and report back. Marking as solved for now.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Am facing the same issue with the followed steps.
VS 2008 Professional. 2008 Team Explorer, 2008 SP1 and 2008 GDR Update for TFS. 

Now I tried to connect with MSSCCI provider which i have downloaded from followed url. But still am getting error saying "This plugin is intended for older version of visual studio. Please use team explorer"
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=12128

Comment: You need to download the 2010, 2013 MSSCCI provider and install Team Explorer 2010, 2013 alongside it. @NaveenDesosha See: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M

Comment: I need to connect TFS compatible with VS2008. What ever you mentioned, all are earlier versions. i want only 2008. @jessehouwing

Comment: Then you're put of. Luck